# How to fix: Mismatching (Curly) Brackets

Tags: c#, curly-braces, mismatch

I just started at programming (C#) at uni and have my first exam next friday. But just now, my project started to mismatch all my curly braces and I can't seem to fix it.

To define my problem a bit more: When I place the combination of a opening and closing brackets (i.e. "{}") after a class for example, and continue to create a method (adding a new pair of curly brackets again) the opening bracket of the class matches with the closing bracket of the method. Which results in a "wrong" code. (see code below; the 1 shows which brackets match with each other)

I'm kinda desperate and was hoping you guys could help me out in fixing this.

Thanks in advance!

```
    class KopieForm : Form
     1{
          public KopieForm
          {
              this.Text = "KopieDemo";
              this.BackColor = Color.White;
              this.Size = new Size(680, 340);
              this.Paint += this.KopieDemo;
         1}
      }
```

Comment: `public KopieForm()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your constructor syntax is not correct. You need parenthesis otherwise it won't compile. Try this:

```
    class KopieForm : Form
 {
      public KopieForm() //notice the ()
      {
          this.Text = "KopieDemo";
          this.BackColor = Color.White;
          this.Size = new Size(680, 340);
          this.Paint += this.KopieDemo;
     }
  }
```

Comment: Wow, okay thanks. I'm sorry or my newby-like question ;)

Comment: No problem, everyone has to start somewhere, if this helps you can upvote and mark as the correct answer :)